# Group matching element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

Given a sorted array, I'd like to create a new, 2D array containing arrays of matching elements. Similar to the behavior of python's itertools.groupby

Example:

```
input = ['a','a','a','a','d','e','e','f','h','h','h','i','l','m','n','r','s','s','t','u','v','y','y']

output = [ ['a','a','a','a'], ['d'], ['e','e'], ['f'], ['h','h','h'], ['i'], ['l'], ['m'], ['n'], ['r'], ['s','s'], ['t'], ['u'], ['v'], ['y','y']]
```

Comment: Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the predecessor and add a new array before pushing to last item.

```js
var input = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'r', 's', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'y', 'y'],
    output = input.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        if (aa[i - 1] !== a) {
            r.push([]);
        }
        r[r.length - 1].push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For non sorted items, you could use a closure over a hash table.

```js
var input = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'y', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'm', 'n', 'r', 's', 'y', 'd', 's', 't', 'u', 'v'],
    output = input.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (!hash[a]) {
                hash[a] = [];
                r.push(hash[a]);
            }
            hash[a].push(a);
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);
    
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.join()` with parameter `""`, `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/([a-z]+)(?=\1)\1|[^\1]/g` to match one or more `"a"` through `"z"` followed by captured characters, or not captured group, `.map()`, `.split()`

```js
var input = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'
             , 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f'
             , 'h', 'h', 'h', 'i'
             , 'l', 'm', 'n', 'r'
             , 's', 's', 't', 'u'
             , 'v', 'y', 'y'];

var res = input.join("").match(/([a-z]+)(?=\1)\1|[^\1]/g).map(c => c.split(""));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This will work even if the array is not sorted:

```js
var input = ['a','b','c','d','a','d','e','e','f','h','h','h','i','l','m','n','r','s','s','t','u','v','y','y'];


function group(arr) {
  var hash = {};
  return arr.reduce(function(res, e) {
    if(hash[e] === undefined)         // if we haven't hashed the index for this value
      hash[e] = res.push([e]) - 1;    // then hash the index which is the index of the newly created array that is initialized with e
    else                              // if we have hashed it
      res[hash[e]].push(e);           // then push e to the array at that hashed index
    return res;
  }, []);
}

console.log(group(input));
```

Comment: [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) does not have a `thisArg`.

Comment: @NinaScholz oops! I thought they're all follow the same!